# Deciding between [gifts] and [presents] tags or keeping both?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently 10 questions tagged [gifts](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifts) and 12 tagged [presents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presents).

Examples:

[Too many presents from Grandma - is this bad for my child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/33598/30519)

[English present for a non-English child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27485/30519)

[If I bought a present for a child and gave it to the parents and later they have a birthday party, do I get another gift?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/14046/30519)

All of the above examples are tagged [gifts](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifts) by the way, not [presents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presents).

There exists a slight [difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7981) in meaning, but I'm not sure if it matters in the context of parenting (and we also have a special tag [gifted](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifted)).

**Do we need both tags? And if not, which one should be kept?**

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to keep only **one** of these tags. At least for our purposes, they are identical. This can easily be seen when, for example, looking at the [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifts) tagged [gifts](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifts). Both expressions are used in the bodies of these questions. By having only **one** tag, we improve user experience, because you'll get all the relevant questions when searching for the tag, not just 50% of them.

I suggest to keep [presents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presents) and make *gifts* its *tag synonym*. It's more clear and concrete. Gift is broader, e. g. the "gift of hope", and we already have another tag [gifted](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gifted), so we are really fool-proof with [presents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presents). There is not much sense in a tag for present meaning *now*. *Gifts* is a bit shorter, though. Still, I think that *presents* is the better candidate.